# My C code is not counting properly word and sentences, but counting char

Tags: c, cs50

I am making a C program to count the number of letters, words & sentences.  But the `if` condition for counting words and sentences doesn't check for the null character. Can anyone help me: what am I doing wrong?

However if condition for counting number of characters is checking for null character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string("text: ");
    int p=0,q=0,r,j=0,k=0;
    {
        printf("Your Text is : %s\n", text);
    }
    for(p=0,r=strlen(text); p<r; p++)
    {
        // for counting Letters.
        if (text[p]!= ' ' && text[p]!= '\0' && text[p]!='-' && text[p]!='_' && text[p]!= '.')
        {
            q++;
        }
        // for counting Words.
        else if (text[p]==' ' || text[p]== '-' || text[p]== '\0'  || text[p]=='_')
        {
            j++;
        }
        // for counting Sentences.
        else if (text[p]== '.' || text[p]== '!' || text[p]== '\0')
        {
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("no.of chars is %i\n",q);
    printf("no.of words is %i\n",j);
    printf("no.of sentences is %i\n",k);
}
```

***included cs50 Library to get string input***

Comment: "doesn't checks for null character". Can you please describe how you are coming to that conclusion? What is the exact input, expected result and actual result?

Comment: There's no need to check for the null character in the loop body. `r = strlen(text)` returns the number of characters up to the null character. The loop condiction enforces `p < r`, so all `text[p]` are not the null character. (A shorter way to loop would be `for (p = 0; text[p] != '\0'; p++) ...`, where the text for the null character is explicit.)

Comment: The end of a sentence also is the end of a word.

Comment: Since `text[p]` is never null you can use `if (strchr(".!", text[p]))` instead of `if (text[p]== '.' || text[p]== '!' || text[p]== '\0')` - and for the negated conditions `if (! strchr(" -_.", text[p]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are expecting that any text is a sentence but it never counted by your code because your code will never get into the analysis on null character as long as it will never be a part of the string.

C Strings are nothing but array of characters ended with null character (‘\0’).
This null character indicates the end of the string.
Strings are always enclosed by double quotes. Whereas, character is enclosed by single quotes in C.

That means that your string ends with null, i.e. everything that is BEFORE the end is a string body but not the NULL itself.

You may simply change your code in the way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string("text: ");
    int p=0,q=0,r,j=0,k=0;
    {
        printf("Your Text is : %s\n", text);
    }
    for(p=0,r=strlen(text); p<r; p++)
    {
        // for counting Letters.
        if (text[p]!= ' ' && text[p]!='-' && text[p]!='_' && text[p]!= '.')
        {
            q++;
        }
        // for counting Words.
        else if (text[p]==' ' || text[p]== '-' ||  text[p]=='_')
        {
            j++;
        }
        // for counting Sentences.
        else if (text[p]== '.' || text[p]== '!' || text[p]== '\0')
        {
            k++;
        }
    }
        if ( q>0 && text[strlen(text)-1]!='.' && text[strlen(text)-1]!='!')
            { 
              j++;
              k++;
            }
        printf("no.of chars is %i\n",q);
        printf("no.of words is %i\n",j);
        printf("no.of sentences is %i\n",k);

}
```

The logic behind the change is the following:

You do not need to check for the null value while you are in the string body looking into the single char. That is because as I already mentioned useless.
After you parse the whole string all you have to do to ensure that there was at least a single character (i>0) and then following the logic that you reach the end of the string you automatically reach the end of the word and end of the sentence.

Comment: When a sentence contain fullstop '.' it prints no. Of sentences 2.

Comment: True! Same goes if '!' is the last symbol. I have extended the check for the incorrect end of text, i.e. no punctuation!